# os.path.exists returns False on Windows although file exists (MAX_PATH 260 Windows API problem?)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, os.path

I am getting a *false negative* on a file that exists with os.path.exists.

```
path = '\\\\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\\Data2San\\p3061\\Proteomics\\TIMSTOF_1\\spfammatter_20200317\\3-17-2020_22-17-14_200ngHeLa_stdPASEF_100minGT__MSdataReduction_moderate_Rep1_520_1_Slot1-46.d\\stdPASEF_100minGT_MSdataReduction_moderate_520.m\\microTOFQImpacTemAcquisition.method'

os.path.exists(path) # returns false

len(path) # returns 260
```

I did some googling and what I found is:

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

Is there a different python API that can handle paths of that length I could use?

Some windows tools can't handle those paths (although I did create this file using robocopy which is a windows tool).

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> ls \\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\Data2San\p3061\Proteomics\TIMSTOF_1\spfammatter_20200317\3-17-2020_22-17-1
4_200ngHeLa_stdPASEF_100minGT__MSdataReduction_moderate_Rep1_520_1_Slot1-46.d\stdPASEF_100minGT_MSdataReduction_moderate
_520.m\


    Directory: \\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\Data2San\p3061\Proteomics\TIMSTOF_1\spfammatter_20200317\3-17-2020_22-17-14_200n
    gHeLa_stdPASEF_100minGT__MSdataReduction_moderate_Rep1_520_1_Slot1-46.d\stdPASEF_100minGT_MSdataReduction_moderate_
    520.m


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------        3/18/2020  12:45 AM            156 desktop.ini
------        3/17/2020  10:17 PM          14301 hystar.method
------        3/18/2020  12:45 AM              0 lock.file
------        3/18/2020  12:45 AM         129055 microTOFQImpacTemAcquisition.method
```

but

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> ls \\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\Data2San\p3061\Proteomics\TIMSTOF_1\spfammatter_20200317\3-17-2020_22-17-1
4_200ngHeLa_stdPASEF_100minGT__MSdataReduction_moderate_Rep1_520_1_Slot1-46.d\stdPASEF_100minGT_MSdataReduction_moderate
_520.m\microTOFQImpacTemAcquisition.method
ls : Cannot find path '\\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\Data2San\p3061\Proteomics\TIMSTOF_1\spfammatter_20200317\3-17-2020_22-17
-14_200ngHeLa_stdPASEF_100minGT__MSdataReduction_moderate_Rep1_520_1_Slot1-46.d\stdPASEF_100minGT_MSdataReduction_moder
ate_520.m\microTOFQImpacTemAcquisition.method' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls \\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\Data2San\p3061\Proteomics\TIMSTOF_1\spfamm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\fgcz-biobeame...uisition.method:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am using Python 3.7.7 64bit

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize > 2**32
True
```

Comment: you can use \\\\?\\UNC\\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\\Data2San\\p3061... path - so \\?\UNC\ prefix instead \\

Comment: In Windows 10, [enabling long-path support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) in the registry will enable long normalized DOS/UNC paths in Python 3.6+, without requiring an extended (non-normalized) "\\?\" device path.

Comment: That said, if you need to support Windows 8 or Windows 10 systems that do not have long-path support enabled, then an extended device path is the best option, as demonstrated by RbMm above. You could also define the path up to the last directory as a mapped drive or a symbolic link, but those options alter the system configuration or filesystem, with the potential for side effects.

Comment: @rbmm could you give a reference please - point me to a python docu. Can't get it working with os.path.exists. '\\\\?\\UNC\\fgcz-biobeamer.uzh.ch\\Da....' always returns False.

Comment: this is not related to python, but for win32 file api layer. dos path \\server translated to  \??\UNC\server and \\?\UNC\server translated to \??\UNC\server. so both \\server and \\?\UNC\server translated to the same string. in general. but exist exceptions, some api can do own translation. i dont know to which win32 api translated call `os.path.exists` (`GetFileAttributes[Ex]W` ? in this case must work). for this need debug code and look

Comment: @RbMm, `os.path.exists` calls `os.stat`, which follows symlinks and other reparse points. The common path for `stat` is to call `CreateFileW` and then `GetFileInformationByHandle`. The `CreateFileW` call should succeed if an extended path is used, e.g. `os.path.exists('\\\\?\\UNC\\' + path[2:])` (where `path` is a UNC path). If it returns `False`, the OP should check `os.stat('\\\\?\\UNC\\' + path[2:])` to see the exception that's raised, since `exists` is coded to ignore most OS exceptions.